# could not find function "symbolicInt"

Tags: r, derivative, integral

I simply cannot get these functions: `symbolicInt` and `integral`. Not sure why. I just re-installed everthing. I thought maybe it was becuase of the libraries but I tried each library, by itself; did not work.
For example, according to documentation of
[Document of symbolicInt](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mosaic/versions/0.14.4/topics/symbolicInt)

[Document of integral](https://dtkaplan.github.io/RforCalculus/integrals-and-integration.html)
Current R Versions:
R 4.2
R42-tools are downloaded.

Code:

```
library('mosaic') 
library('mosaicCore')
library('mosaicCalc')

f <- function(x){a * x^2 ~ x}

F = antiD(a * x^2 ~ x, a = 1)
F

symbolicInt(f )

f = integral( 3*x**2 ~ x)
f(from=1,to=4)
```

Result:

```
Error in symbolicInt(f) : could not find function "symbolicInt"

Error in integral(f ~ x) : could not find function "integral"
```

Edit: I am able to use symbolicInt by mosaicCalc:::symbolicInt ; but I cannot process this function:

`(x/sigma**2)*exp((-x**2)/2*sigma**2 )`

It gives following error:

`Error in .intArith(form, ...) :`

`Error: symbolic algorithm gave up`

`6. stop("Error: symbolic algorithm gave up")`

`5. .intArith(form, ...)`

`4. symbolicAntiD(lform, ...)`

`3. .intArith(form, ...)`

`2. symbolicAntiD(form, ...)`

`1. sI((x/sigma^2) * exp((-x^2)/2 * sigma^2) + 1 ~ x)`

Comment: I loaded the package as well.  Despite the documentation, I don't see those functions in there either. You can use ls("package:mosaic") to get a list of all the functions in the package. Not there.

Comment: The documentation you link to is from version 0.14.4 and the current version of the package is 1.8.3 - likely the function got removed or subsumed by some other function.

Comment: The `symbolicInt()` function is not exported from the `mosaicCalc` namespace.  You can access it with `mosaicCalc:::symbolicInt()`

Comment: Not sure about `integral()`, but you may want to have a look at `antiD()`.  Your code above would turn into `f <- antiD(3*x**2 ~ x); f(4)-f(2)`.  You could also use `integrate()` from the `stats` package, which would look like `integrate(function(x)3*x**2, 1,4)`.

Comment: @DaveArmstrong you`re right. Probably this is the reason. I can run symbolicInt by mosaicCalc:::symbolicInt() ,but mosaicCalc:::symbolicInt() does not work like how it was proposed. It just worsks like antiD. I was expecting better than that for visualization.

Comment: @stomper hi, even in the package mosaic, it was not in there. But I see there is another problem. For example, @DaveArmstrong also said that calling function by `mosaicCalc:::symbolicInt() ` When I did this, it worked; but it did not work when I called library('mosaicCalc') which means there can be a location problem for the packages.
And thank you both, at least I have a clue for main problem and can run the function.
But I cannot still process this function: mosaicCalc:::symbolicInt( exp(2)**x ~ x)

Comment: @masiva What exactly are you trying to do with these functions?

Comment: I would like to create cdf functions of pdf functions from different distributions. I just find out that `
mosaicCalc:::symbolicInt( (-1/2) + (1/exp(x)) ~ x 
# Gives error
mosaicCalc:::symbolicInt( (-1/2) + (1/exp(x)*1) ~ x) 
# It does not give error